# Trying to form DataFrame from API, but the function is getting Name error

Tags: python, pandas, api

```py
import requests # get connection
import pandas as pd
import json

def get_info(data):
    data=[]
    source=[]
    published_date=[]
    adx_keywords=[]
    byline=[]
    title=[]
    abstract=[]
    des_facet=[]
    per_facet=[]
    media=[]
    Api_Key=''
    url='https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/viewed/7.json?api-key=' # key redacted
    response=requests.get(url).json()

    for i in response['results']:
        source.append(i['source'])
        published_date.append(i['published_date'])
        adx_keywords.append(i['adx_keywords'])
        byline.append(i['byline'])
        title.append(i['title'])
        abstract.append(i['abstract'])
        des_facet.append(i['des_facet'])
        per_facet.append(i['per_facet'])
        media.append(i['media'])
        data=data.append({'source':source,'published_date':published_date,'adx_keywords':adx_keywords,byline':byline, 'title':title,'abstract':abstract,'des_facet':des_facet,
                               'per_facet':per_facet,'media':media})
    df=df.append(d)
    return df
```

```
df NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-292-00cf07b74dcd> in <module>()
----> 1 df

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: As you can see - even on the color-highlighting in Stackoverflow - the hyphens `'` are set wrong. Starting at `':byline'`

Answer (score 0):

your hyphens are in the the wrong place

before:

```
data=data.append({'source':source,'published_date':published_date,'adx_keywords':adx_keywords,byline':byline, 'title':title,'abstract':abstract,'des_facet':des_facet,
                               'per_facet':per_facet,'media':media})
```

after:

```
data=data.append({'source':source,'published_date':published_date,'adx_keywords':adx_keywords,'byline':byline, 'title':title, 'abstract':abstract,'des_facet':des_facet,
                       'per_facet':per_facet,'media':media})
```